# webpage not printing winsock information

Tags: php, mysql, c

I am trying to send data from a `winsock` application to a PHP script. I have already tried various header types without any success and I can't seem to find enough information.

Data is sent, but the PHP script is not printing any results, so I think the error is headers types.

**C Winsock code**

```
    int main()
{
    SOCKADDR_IN sock;
    SOCKET s;
    WSADATA wsa;
    int lengthofrequest = 0;
    char httprequest[180] =
        "POST /test.php?name=alex&password=secret HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n"
        "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
        "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
        "Connection: close\r\n"
        "Content-Length: 25\r\n"
        "\r\n";

    lengthofrequest = strlen(httprequest);

    // init winsock

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
        return WSASYSNOTREADY;

    sock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sock.sin_port = htons(80);

    // create socket

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return 1;

    // connect to the http panel

    int conn = connect(s, (SOCKADDR*)&sock, sizeof(sock));
    if (conn < 0)
        return 1;

    // send http header

    send(s, httprequest, lengthofrequest, 0);

    // close socket

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['password']))
    {
       echo $_POST['name'];
       echo $_POST['password'];
    }
?>
```

I would appreciate any help or guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Try changing 1.1 to 1.0

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing post and get
Use $_GET to access your data because your data is appended to the url

Try this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['name'], $_GET['password']))
    {
       echo $_GET['name'];
       echo $_GET['password'];
    }
```

this should work but you should consider changing your request type to GET in the C code as well to make your code clear and simple

What you are doin here is ambiguous:

```
 "POST /test.php?name=alex&password=secret HTTP/1.1\r\n"
```

Because you are sending get parameters using post and the post body is actually empty.

Also you should omit  **?>** at the end of your php script.